Using refactoring functionality within an Intellij plugin
How do I call existing refactoring functionality (Rename, Extract Delagate, etc.) within an Intellij plugin?
The only existing discussion I've found is in a forum from over 20 years ago: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206802075-Refactoring-API.
I took a look at the RefactoringFactory class but it seems to only support rename and create safe delete functionality.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206789785-Invoke-refactoring-from-plugin mentions RefactoringActionHandlerFactory which also seems to support safe delete. There may be RefactoringActionHandlers for other options.
